# Why Google Play Services apk is not updating

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a Sony Xperia running Android 4.4.4 (KitKat), and Google Play Services 4.4.52. My app is built against the latest Play Services v7.3.0, and as such, is correctly requesting the user to upgrade to the latest Play Services. My questions are:

1. Why has Android not automatically downloaded this update? I recently reset the phone back to factory, and it  is prompting me to update a handful of other apps, but it appears Play Services is not being automatically updated. It has wifi internet access. I'm concerned  that other users will experience this problem, preventing them from using  the  app until they update. The Google APIs for Android overview page [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview%20here) indicates  updates are done silently and within days of each release.
2. Why can't I find Google Play Services through a search on the Play Store? It seems can only find it with a direct link to it via the play store.

Thanks all

Comment: latest version is 7.8 ... 1 you need to run "google play(shop)"  at least once before automatic upgrade 2. and? ... you can add update code (with few lines) if you are using google play service in your app(it is all in offical guide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why has Android not automatically downloaded this update? I recently
>   reset the phone back to factory, and it is prompting me to update a
>   handful of other apps, but it appears Play Services is not being
>   automatically updated. It has wifi internet access. I'm concerned that
>   other users will experience this problem, preventing them from using
>   the app until they update. The Google APIs for Android overview page
>   here indicates updates are done silently and within days of each
>   release.

I'd suggested you to update Google Play Services to 7.5.0, as it is the latest version. This should fix the update issue.

> Why can't I find Google Play Services through a search on the Play
>   Store? It seems can only find it with a direct link to it via the play
>   store.

Check your android manifest for app's permissions and min/target sdk versions. There might be something that do not allow you to see your app at Google Play (e.g. something that is not present in your Sony Xperia 4.4.4)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I can definitely upgrade to latest Play Services 7.5.0, but my question is why the phone has not silently and automatically updated it to a more recent version from current version 4.4 already? If users run my  app and are  immediately prompted to "upgrade their Google Play Services", they will probably just cancel and uninstall the app....

Comment: If users of your app have outdated Google Play Services, not just your app will ask them to update it. But your project will still need to user the latest version